# Qt - Compilation Error: Couldn't change working directory

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qml, chromium-embedded

I am trying to compile [oxideqt](https://launchpad.net/oxide), a QML API for Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF), but I am experiencing an error:

```
11:13:58: Running steps for project oxideqt...
11:13:58: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:13:58: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    cd qt\lib\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe C:\Users\simon\Documents\oxide\qt\lib\lib.pro -spec win32-msvc2010 -o Makefile ) && C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile
    C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
    cd C:/Users/simon/Documents/oxide; ./build/gyp_oxide -IC:/Users/simon/Documents/oxide/qt/qt.gypi -Doxide_qt_libversion=0
Couldn't change working directory to C:/Users/simon/Documents/oxide; ./build/gyp_oxide -IC:/Users/simon/Documents/oxide/qt/qt.gypi -Doxide_qt_libversion=0.
jom: C:\Users\simon\Documents\build-oxideqt-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release\qt\lib\Makefile.Release [C:\Users\simon\Documents\oxide\Makefile.oxide] Error 1
jom: C:\Users\simon\Documents\build-oxideqt-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release\qt\lib\Makefile [release] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\simon\Documents\build-oxideqt-Desktop_Qt_5_1_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release\Makefile [sub-qt-lib-lib-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
11:13:58: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project oxideqt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.1 MSVC2010 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

It looks like that it is doing a `cd` on `C:/Users/simon/Documents/oxide; ./build/gyp_oxide -IC:/Users/simon/Documents/oxide/qt/qt.gypi -Doxide_qt_libversion=0`, but I cannot find out which script is doing the `cd`.

The following are the associated .pro files:

oxideqt.pro (top level .pro)

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered

lib.file = qt/lib/lib.pro
SUBDIRS += lib

renderer.file = qt/renderer/renderer.pro
SUBDIRS += renderer

sandbox.file = qt/sandbox/sandbox.pro
SUBDIRS += sandbox

qmlplugin.file = qt/qmlplugin/qmlplugin.pro
SUBDIRS += qmlplugin

testutils.file = qt/tests/utils/testutils.pro
SUBDIRS += testutils

qmltests.file = qt/tests/qmltests/qmltests.pro
SUBDIRS += qmltests

QMAKE_CLEAN += -r \
    $${OXIDE_SRC_ROOT}/Makefile.oxide \
    `find $$OXIDE_SRC_ROOT -name \"*.target.oxide.mk\"` \
    $$CHROMIUM_OUT_DIR
```

lib.pro

```
CONFIG += gyp disable_check
TARGET = oxide-qt
GYP_TYPE = lib

include($${OXIDE_QMAKE_PATH}/oxide_variables.pri)

GYP_LIBVERSION = $$OXIDE_QT_LIBVERSION

resources.path = $$LIBEXECDIR
resources.files = \
    $${CHROMIUM_OUT_PLAT_DIR}/oxide.pak \
    $${CHROMIUM_OUT_PLAT_DIR}/oxide_100_percent.pak
resources.CONFIG = no_check_exist
INSTALLS += resources
```

Comment: "but I cannot find out which script is doing the cd." - That'd be one of the Makefile's generated by qmake. Does the path exist?

Comment: `C:/Users/simon/Documents/oxide` exists, but, if you append everything afterwards, it does not. That looks like what it's doing.

Answer (score 3):

A possible reason and solution:

This looks like it is for `sh`, not for `cmd.exe`:

```
cd C:/Users/simon/Documents/oxide; ./build/gyp_oxide -IC:/Users/simon/Documents/oxide/qt/qt.gypi -Doxide_qt_libversion=0
```

If so, it may be due to faulty auto-detection of shell. A reason for that happening might be that there is `sh.exe` in the PATH. So, find out where it is, and either remove the folder from PATH or rename the file to `sh_.exe` or whatever.

To find it, this should find the file ([a link](https://superuser.com/questions/21067/windows-equivalent-of-whereis)) at *the correct `cmd.exe` prompt for the build environment*:

```
where sh
```

Note that if you have a lot of stuff installed, you may have *several* of them in your PATH, so after getting rid of first, check again... If still not solved, try removing `bash` from PATH too (though I have not seen that causing trouble). Also remember to restart the IDE or the command prompt if you edit system PATH, for the change to take effect. And then *remember to re-run `qmake`*.

Comment: But I cannot find `sh` anywhere on my disk. When I do `where sh`, I get `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`.

Comment: Well then, root of the problem is something else :(. But I am pretty sure the symptom is as I think, something generates *sh* command, when it should generate *cmd.exe* command, maybe that will help in finding a solution. You could try "find in files" or grep in project folder for string `gyp_oxide` and see if you find where the offending command is coming from.

Comment: Another possible place for problem (basically bug in Qt installation in this case) may be in *qmake* configuration files. Command `qmake -query` (with right qmake) should tell where they are located for that *qmake*. You can look for *jom*-related stuff under there for you compiler toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~oxide-developers/oxide/oxide.trunk/view/head:/build/gyp_oxide is a python-script, which the make tries to start. Is python.exe in your PATH-variable?

Kim Kulling

Comment: Yes, my PATH variable contains the directory that contains python.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked over the configuration of the whole pro-files and found a lot of unix-specific paths like /usr/local. Is window as a build target at all supported?
As mentioned before the build script cannot work with cd ; command . 
Maybe you can try to run it using cygwin?

Kim Kulling